# Error thrown while updating attribute value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the body of a screen in flutter based on whether there is any record in my table.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widgets/appDrawer.dart';
import '../widgets/emptyHomeScreen.dart';
import '../data/database.dart';
import '../widgets/filledHomeScreen.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final dbHelper = DBProvider.db;
  int count;

  _MyHomePageState() {
    dbHelper.getCount().then((val) => setState(() {
          count = val;
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('All Files'),
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      floatingActionButton: buildFloatingActionButton(context),
      body: Center(
        child: count > 0 ? FilledHomeScreen() : EmptyHomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I tried to run my app, error was thrown for just a fraction of second and then the app just worked fine.
How do I fix it?

The error thrown was:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#4d44c):
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(0)
```

The code for the function getCount() is:

```
  Future<int> getCount() async {
    //database connection
    final Database db = await database;
    var x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) from documents');
    int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
    return count;
  }
```

Is there any way of doing this by converting the statefulwidget to statelesswidget?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final dbHelper = DBProvider.db;
  int count;

  _MyHomePageState() {
    dbHelper.getCount().then((val) => setState(() {
          count = val;
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('All Scans'),
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      floatingActionButton: buildFloatingActionButton(context),
      body: Center(
        child: count != null && count > 0 ? FilledHomeScreen() : EmptyHomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```